# alternate methods lead to contradictory answers (conditional pdf)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> let $T_1, T_2, T_3$ be Exponential($\lambda$), all independent and let $Y_1 = T_1$, $Y_2 = T_1 + T_2$, $Y_3 = T_1 + T_2 + T_3$

Find pdf of $Y_2$ given $Y_1 = y_1$

First method:

- computed the pdf for $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$ using the convolution integral and found that they only depend on the variable of parametrization and are thus independent. Also find $Y_2$ is Gamma(2, $\lambda)$ and $Y_3$ is Gamma(3, $\lambda$)
- deduce conditional pdf is just pdf of $Y_2$

Second method:

see that $P(Y_2 \le y_2 | Y_1 = y_1) = P(y_1 + T_2 \le y_2) = P(T_2 \le y_2 - y_1)$

making the conditional pdf equivalent to $f_{T_2}(y_2 - y_1)$

Question:

which method is correct and what is wrong with the other one?

My intuition is the second one is incorrect, since you seem to be speaking only of the "and" event ... and you cannot have $P(Y_1 = y_1)$ alone.

Comment: MGF method here would be very effective

Answer (score 1):

Method $2$ is correct.  $$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y_2 \le y_2 \mid Y_1 = y_1] &= \Pr[T_1 + T_2 \le y_2 \mid T_1 = y_1] \\
&= \Pr[T_2 \le y_2 - y_1] \\
&= F_{T_2}(y_2 - y_1), \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
hence $$f_{Y_2 \mid Y_1}(y_2 \mid y_1) = f_{T_2}(y_2 - y_1) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(y_2 - y_1)}, \quad y_2 \ge y_1. \tag{2}$$
This is a location-shifted exponential density with rate $\lambda$.

Method $1$ is incorrect because $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are not independent.  We can immediately see that $$Y_2 = T_1 + T_2 = Y_1 + T_2,$$ so for instance,
$$\Pr[Y_1 > 1 \mid Y_2 = 1] = \Pr[Y_1 > 1 \mid Y_1 = 1 - T_2] = 0 \ne \Pr[Y_1 > 1].$$
Although it is true that
$$Y_2 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,\lambda), \\
f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \frac{\lambda^2 y_2 e^{-\lambda y_2}}{\Gamma(2)} = \lambda^2 y_2 e^{-\lambda y_2}, \quad y_2 \ge 0, \tag{3}$$
this is just the marginal density of $Y_2$.  The joint density of $Y_1, Y_2$ is
$$f_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1, y_2) = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y_2}, \quad 0 \le y_1 \le y_2. \tag{4}$$
Integrating this joint density with respect to $y_1$ on the interval $0 \le y_1 \le y_2$ yields $(3)$; i.e.,
$$f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \int_{y_1 = 0}^{y_2} f_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1, y_2) \, dy_1.$$  Integrating with respect to $y_2$ yields the marginal for $Y_1$, which as we already know, is the exponential density with rate $\lambda$:
$$f_{Y_1}(y_2) = \int_{y_2 = y_1}^\infty f_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1, y_2) \, dy_2 = \lambda e^{-\lambda y_1}, \quad y_1 \ge 0.$$

Comment: I'm not clear on how we see that they are not independent. The reason I assumed independence was due to what I had learned: when discussing $f_{x, y}(x, y) = 1_{0 \le x \le y} e^{-y}$, my professor found the marginals and then defined $Z = Y - X$, found $f_{z|x}(z|x) = 1_{z \ge 0} e^{-z}$ (via first computing $f_{y|x}(y|x)$) and concluded by looking at $f_{x, z} (x,z) = f_{z|x} (z|x) f_x (x)$ that they are "independent", by pointing out that "x is gone" in $f_{z|x} (z|x)$. At the time, and still, I didn't understand that reasoning, but that was the reasoning I used to deduce independence here.

Comment: @user8393252 The *conditional* distribution $Y_2 - Y_1 \mid Y_1$ is independent of $Y_1$, but $Y_2$ is not itself independent of $Y_1$.  Recall that events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\Pr[A \mid B] = \Pr[A]$.  So variables $Y_1, Y_2$ are not independent because if I tell you that $Y_2 = 1$, this immediately forces $Y_1 \le 1$ because all of the random variables are positive.  So the conditional probability $\Pr[Y_1 > 1 \mid Y_2 = 1]$ is zero and cannot equal the unconditional $\Pr[Y_1 > 1]$ which is positive.

Comment: How are you able to deduce this rigorously? I'm having a hard time with the notation, given that $Y_2 = 1$ is a zero probability event. I've only seen the usage of something like that within an integral, where the condition varies. For this reason, the second method does not make much sense to me, and I don't see how you are able to derive it and further get the joint PDF alongside constraints on $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: @user8393252 Okay, so if you don't accept $Y_2 = 1$, change it to $Y_2 < 1$.  So if $Y_2 = T_1 + T_2$ and $Y_1 = T_1$, what is $\Pr[Y_1 > 1 \mid Y_2 < 1]$?  Calculate it.  Then calculate $\Pr[Y_1 > 1]$.  Unfortunately, I think your difficulties with this concept will require substantial review of prior material, as the nature of your questions suggests to me that this question is presently beyond the scope of your knowledge.

Comment: I'm happy with conditionals for discrete, but this is my first experience with conditionals for continuous r.v and I am having trouble seeing how the second method yields a correct solution, given $Y_1 = y_1$ has probability 0, and you cannot condition on a probability 0 event. This is what I had stated in my question as well. I've never seen a correct calculation done to derive a conditional pdf like this question asks and am in particular confused by the constraints and where they come from.

Comment: @user8393252 Under such reasoning, you would not be able to observe any outcome of a continuous random variable, since no specific outcome has positive probability.  Yet we observe them all the time.  Once the value is observed, it has happened.  Given that it has happened, what is the conditional distribution of some other variable?  That's the question being asked.  If this is confusing, you may need to review probability spaces from a measure-theoretic view.

Answer (score 1):

> computed the pdf for $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ using the convolution integral and found that they only depend on the variable of parametrization and are thus independent. Also find $Y_2$ is $\Gamma(2, λ)$ and $Y_3$ is $\Gamma(3, λ$.

The *marginal* distributions of $Y_1, Y_2,$ and $Y_3$ *do* only depend on the parameter, $\lambda$.  Indeed, they are $Y_1\sim\Gamma(1,\lambda)$, $Y_2\sim\Gamma(2,\lambda),$ and $Y_3\sim\Gamma(3,\lambda)$.

However, this ***does not*** imply that they are independent.  The marginal distributions *on their own* do not tell you about independence.

Rather, you would need to verify whether $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = f_{Y_1}(y_1)f_{Y_2}(y_2)$ is true or not.

> see that $P(Y_2 \le y_2 \mid Y_1 = y_1) = P(y_1 + T_2 \le y_2) = P(T_2 \le y_2 - y_1)$ making the conditional pdf equivalent to $f_{T_2}(y_2 - y_1)$

Indeed.  $T_2=Y_2-Y_1$, so therefore: $(Y_2-Y_1)\mid Y_1\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)$

$$f_{Y_2\mid Y_1}(y_2\mid y_1) = f_{T_2}(y_2-y_1)$$

This should be sensible to you, as you have performed the convolutions, and have basically already used this.

$$\begin{align}f_{Y_2}(y_2) &= \int_\Bbb R f_{Y_1}(y_1) f_{Y_2\mid Y_1}(y_2-y_1)\,\mathrm d y_1 &&\text{By LOTP}\\ &=\int_\Bbb R f_{T_1}(y_1) f_{T_2}(y_2-y_1)\,\mathrm d y_1 &&\text{as above.}\end{align}$$

Comment: By variable of parameterization, I had meant $y_2$ in $f_{Y_2} (y_2)$ for example. When discussing $f_{x, y}(x, y) = 1_{0 \le x \le y} e^{-y}$, my professor found the marginals and then defined $Z = Y - X$, found $f_{z|x}(z|x) = 1_{z \ge 0} e^{-z}$ (via first computing $f_{y|x}(y|x)$) and concluded by looking at $f_{x, z} (x,z) = f_{z|x} (z|x) f_x (x)$ that they are "independent", by pointing out that "x is gone" in $f_{z|x} (z|x)$. At the time, and still, I didn't understand that reasoning, but that was the reasoning I used to deduce independence here.

Comment: @user8393252  That reasoning is that the **conditional** $f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x)$ (being $\mathrm e^{-z}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}$) is a monovariant function of $z$; which means that it is *in this case* also the *marginal* $f_Z(z)$.  $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) &=\int_\Bbb R f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x)\,f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ &= (\mathrm e^{-z}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z})\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ &= f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x) \end{align}$$  A *marginal pdf* is always monovariant, by definion.  Thus to determine independence, you must *first* find the conditional pdf.

Comment: If a bivariant joint pdf is *separatable* into the product of two monovariant functions (including the supports), then those random variables are independent.  $$f_{U,V}(u,v)= g(u)\cdot h(v)\implies U\perp V$$

Comment: For the monovariant of the conditional, isn't it only defined if $x \ge 0$ (with $z$ also defined in terms of $x$), so I'm having trouble seeing the independent with $x$. In particular, we lose the information that $x \ge 0$